# Get OUTPUT of stored procedure when executing it as a dynamic query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that looks something like this,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_schema.sp_do   
    @param1 VARCHAR(50),   
    @param2 VARCHAR(MAX),
    @count INT OUTPUT
AS   
    -- execute logic
    SET @count = (SELECT col1 FROM @tbl)
GO
```

This will basically execute some logic and set the `@count` output variable to some value, which I want to be able to access when the stored procedure is actually called.

I am able to execute it like this and get the value of the output,

```
DECLARE @i INT
EXEC my_schema.sp_do 'val1', 'val2', @i OUTPUT;
PRINT @i
```

However, when I am actually making use of this, I am building this query dynamically. How exactly can I execute this query as a string and still be able to access the output?

For instance,

```
DECLARE @i INT
SET @sql = 'EXEC my_schema.sp_do ''val1'', ''val2'', @i OUTPUT;'
exec sp_executesql @sql
PRINT @i
```

I know this does not work. How can I do this correctly?

If I understand correctly, I need to pass names and the data types of the parameters as the second argument to `sp_executesql`? Since I am building the query dynamically, I cannot do this. I don't have access to the data types, I only have access to the parameter names and the values.

If there is an entirely better way to do this, I am open to that as well.

Note: As to why I need to do this, I have several stored procedures and each of them have their own parameters. These stored procedures are defined by a number of database admins. This essentially means that the numbers of SPs will increase/decrease over time (however, the structure will remain somewhat the same: the count OUTPUT needs to be available in every SP). There are users who configure these stored procedures to be executed by providing the parameters and a kind of alias to the stored procedure itself (this information is stored in table, let's call it the metadata table). This is done through an application. I am in the process of writing a controller of sorts that will query the metadata table and execute each of these configured stored procedures on a schedule.

Using the metadata table, I can build the path to each stored procedure and I can pass in the parameters. However, I am not entirely sure how the data types of the parameters can be accessed. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: *"Since I am building the query dynamically, I cannot do this"* You *have* to. If you don't know what the data types are, this smells like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info). Why are you building the statement dynamically in the first place?

Comment: The values for the parameters are coming from user input. In this case, it is their responsibility to enter values that match the data types of the parameters. I am executing the query dynamically for this reason as well, due to the fact that I am incorporating user input.

Comment: That doesn't really explain anything, if I am honest. If the application is executing the procedure `my_schema.sp_do` then *you* know the data types of the procedure; there is no need for dynamic SQL. Why does your application not just pass the user entered value(s), which should be strongly type, to the procedure.

Comment: You can pass output parameters to `sp_executesql` like any other procedure, e.g. `declare @output INT; exec sp_executesql N'set @output = 1', N'@output INT OUTPUT', @output = @output OUTPUT; select @output;`. However, once you get to multiple layers of dynamic execution like this you hit diminishing returns quickly, and you may as well have the client code build the query directly. This also avoids a false sense of security that you're somehow avoiding arbitrary code execution this way, if your dynamic code isn't actually ensuring that (which it often isn't).

Comment: @Larnu I have updated the question with what I am trying to do. Can you please check if that helps shed more light on the problem?

Comment: @JeroenMostert My SP has other parameters as well. Those would need to be passed in, yes?

Comment: Client code can just call any stored procedure you like *directly*. There is no need to go through `sp_executesql`, and indeed it just makes things more complicated. The fact that the number or type of parameters is variable is not relevant here: your T-SQL code somehow needs to manage that just like your client code would. Ironically or otherwise, T-SQL is not a good language to write dynamic execution of T-SQL in, and a bare string with an `EXEC` statement makes for poor input.

Comment: @JeroenMostert There is actually no client code. I am forced to write this in T-SQL and then call the 'controller' from an Azure Data Factory pipeline. I would prefer to do it another way as well, however, this has been architected as such.

Comment: This definitely is turning into more and more of an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) in my opinion. ADF pipelines aren't even mentioned in the above, and they seem to be an integral part of the logic flow. I suggest that perhaps you take a step back and explain the *actual* problem you are trying to solve; explain the *X*, not the *Y*.

Comment: Doing this in T-SQL is really quite complicated. It sound straightforward until you actually sit down to implement it. Shuttling out arbitrary `OUTPUT` parameters is very hard; if it's just the one `OUTPUT` parameter with the same type all the time it's easier, but still ugly. It requires getting funny with `STRING_AGG`, escaping literals of various types and/or creating dynamic tables to hold values, it's... just a huge, huge mess. You *have* client code in that *something* invokes a query on the database end that *isn't* T-SQL; focus on making that bit smarter.

Comment: definitely a XY Problem. SQL is not thinked for this. You should think in some kind of fuction and logic for conversion to do this, and you will return always to the original problem. Or use NoSQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add an output parameter to the call to `sp_executesql`:

```
DECLARE @i int, @sql nvarchar(max);
SET @sql = 'EXEC my_schema.sp_do ''val1'', ''val2'', @i OUTPUT;';
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql, N'@i int OUTPUT', @i OUTPUT;
PRINT @i;
```

- Working example in [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1Yt3-TK4) (minus your specific schema). Though you should always name your parameters, especially if you start building strings within strings within strings, it gets brittle and hard to follow very quickly.

(Though I read the extensive comment thread *after*, and agree generally that this doesn't sound like a very stable solution to implement in T-SQL.)

Comment: This solved my problem, thanks. I too agree that this is not the best way to go about doing this. I would rather do it without T-SQL, but based on certain considerations (and my objections), I have been asked to implement it this way. Thanks again!